# How to connect switches to a power transformer?

Tags: transformer, switches, wiring

I'd like to use two rocker switches. Both are single-pole and include a light bulb on the inside (230 VAC) to control the powering of the system.

I'd like to connect both of them to a transformer with a single primary winding (230 VAC) and double secondary windings (each rated as 26 V), but here's the trick: The red rocker switch is the "head" of the circuit: if the red one is turned off, then nothing should be working (neither +26 V, nor -26V line). But, if I turn on the red switch, the +26 V line must be turned on, while I have an option to turn on the -26 V line with the green switch, or not.
Only turning on the green switch while red is turned off should result in both circuits being turned off.

Here's a chart I've written about how the schematics should work:

```
RED | GREEN | +26V | -26V
 0  |   0   |   0  |   0
 1  |   0   |   1  |   0
 0  |   1   |   0  |   0
 1  |   1   |   1  |   1
```

And here's the schematics:

[image]

Comment: your logic chart needs only three lines ..... when the red switch is off, then the green switch should be a "don't care" state designated as `X`

Comment: Why not just use different switches?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the red switch in the same wire as the fuse - that should be the Live wire.  For AC wiring, you should always switch the "hot"/Live wire, not the Neutral.

I would put the -26V switch in the -26V wire, rather than in the Ground.  Either way would work, but it makes more sense to me to switch the "hot" wire.  The lamp lead for the -26V switch should go to GND, but if it is desigend for 230V, it probably won't light with only 26 volts.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they will come in handy and will change the schematics.
Yes, that's the actualy problem: it won't turn on just on 26 volts. Therefore I'm searching for the alternative wiring, while keeping same components.

Comment: You could try taking the lamp lead to +26V - but it depends on the type of lamp in the switch.  If neon, you'd need more than 80 volts or so to light it.

Comment: It's not neon. It's probably regular lightbulb inside. It's most common rocker switch that can be commercially hound.

Comment: if it's a LED in there it will quite a lot work to light it. if it's a neon you can make the connection shown

Answer (score 0):

In the -26 V circuit, make these changes:

1. Remove the switch and connect the bridge + terminal directly to GND.
2. Insert the SPST switch between either of the bridge "i" terminals and its corresponding transformer wire.

Answer (score 0):

The green switch probably has a bipolar LED with a series resistor inside.

You may be able to modify the switch to work on 1/10 the voltage by replacing the resistor with a suitable lower value.

You can try working the transparent rocker out by trying to deform the housing a bit and pressing the hinge pins (definite possibility of non-reversible damage in this operation, or bits that go 'sproing' never to be seen again) and see what it looks like inside.

There's less worry mucking about in the green switch since it does not see mains voltage and 26VAC is relatively safe from an electrical shock point of view.

Your text does not quite match your truth table, but taking the latter as correct, the switches you show will work, though, as  others have said, I would interrupt one of the transformer wires rather than the bridge ground.